# Matlab string array

Tags: matlab

All i am trying to do is this:

```
    type = cell(size(A));
    ...
    i = find(A == 0);
    type{i} = 'pasok';
```

However it miserably fails is `size(A) > 1` or if `i` is empty.
Is there any workaround for this problem?

**UPDATE -ERROR**

type =

```
[]    []
```

ans =

```
 1     2
```

i =

```
 1     2
```

The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy
 the left hand side.

Error in ellipse (line 48)
type{i} ='pasok';

Comment: 'it miserably fails' doesn't really look like a Matlab error statement to me. If you tell us what the error message is we can provide better help.  If you tell us what you are trying to do we can provide better help, right now I am wondering wha problem you are trying to workaround.  I mean, you already know that the statement `type{i} = 'pasok'` fails when i is either empty or multi-valued, because you have read the error messages and the documentation.  So what is the problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: "'it miserably fails' doesn't really look like a Matlab error statement to me." Every day you learn something new! (+1).

Comment: @Parhs So.... what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EitanT if you read it, it clearly shows that he is getting an error, and wants a workaround

Comment: @ahmet if you read _my comment_, it clearly shows that I'm not asking about the error, but rather about what he's trying to implement.

Comment: ok guys i have update it

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark if i is   [1  2]  i want type{1} and type{2}  to be equal to 'pasok'!

Answer (score 2):

To assign one value to multiple cell-entries at once, you can use

```
[type{i}] = deal('pasok');
```

Note that `type{i}` has to be in square brackets.

Comment: Good answer, I also would use logical indexing `[type{A==0}]=deal('pasok');` as this is usually faster and in my opinion more intuitive.